# Please can someone explain how this program works

Tags: c++

Hello I am trying to work out how this program works and then calculate the values after the code is executed.

This is the code:

```
int a,b,c;
a = 19;
b = 23;
c = 7;
for (a = 0; a <= b; a++)
{
 b = 8;
 c = c + 1;
}
```

The answer that I got for it was.

```
a = 19
b = 8
c = 7
```

Which is wrong and I am really not sure why. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: [The code you show **does not** produce the results you show](https://www.ideone.com/taIiCo).

Comment: You could print a, b, and c inside the loop to get a good sense of how this code works.

Comment: Hello thanks for the comments. I know the code does not make them answers and no I cant change it as it is a question that I need to answer for my revision. There are four possible answers and I chose the wrong one.

But I need to know where I went wrong and how I can go around getting the right answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a step through...

To start, we have

```
 a | b | c 
---|---|---
19 |23 | 7
```

Then we hit:

```
for(a=0; a <= b; a++) {
```

This will immediately set `a=0` and then compare `a <= b`. If true, it'll run the body of the loop, run `a++`, and then check the condition again (repeating until the condition evaluates false). Let's walk through an iteration...

Entering the loop we now have

```
 a | b | c 
---|---|---
 0 |23 | 7
```

`a <= b` is true, so we'll enter the loop and run:

```
b = 8;
c = c + 1;
```

Then we run the increment (`a++`). So after the first loop and increment we'll have

```
 a | b | c 
---|---|---
 1 | 8 | 8
```

Since `a <= b` is still true, we'll enter the loop again and then do another increment...

---

You'll continue until the condition is no longer true. Does this make sense?

Comment: Makes more sense now. Just wondering how come the increment is going up by 1 and not 19 what it originally was?

Comment: @RexRichards Take another look at my answer. The initialization of the `for` loop sets `a = 0`.